# SSMS 18.12.1 crashing intermittently

Tags: ssms, ssms-18

A number of us at my job have had issues with SSMS restarting periodically throughout the day.  This has happened across a number of SSMS versions and over VPN connections as well as on PCs on the local network.  This morning is particularly bad - it's happening about about 20 minute intervals - 0947, 0924, 0851.  Some days are worse than others.

What typically happens is that SSMS will be sitting there idle and - just restart.  This isn't in response to a long query being executed or any obvious user activity.  No error message gets displayed and SSMS typically restarts.

I have a suspicion that this is due to Crowdstrike being run in our environment but have had a challenge pinning this down with complete certainty.

It's worth mentioning that I've reinstalled various versions, multiple times and have done things like delete all references to SSMS in the registry in an attempt to get a clean build.  The fact that this has happened across multiple machines and multiple accounts makes me think this isn't down to just a dodgy install.

It's also worth mentioning that my machine is HP Laptop (AMD Ryzen 5 Pro 5650) with 15.3GB of RAM, only 11GB of which area currently in use.

Has anybody else come across this?

> `
>
> The Windows Error Reporting log entry is as follows:Fault bucket 1344123028005871426, type 5
> Event Name: CLR20r3
> Response: Not available
> Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature:
> P1: Ssms.exe
> P2: 2019.150.18424.0
> P3: 62b10e6f
> P4: PresentationCore
> P5: 4.8.4579.0
> P6: 631946f9
> P7: 4834
> P8: 0
> P9: System.OutOfMemoryException
> P10:
>
> Attached files:
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER6C88.tmp.mdmp
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7265.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7285.tmp.xml
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7283.tmp.csv
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER72E2.tmp.txt
>
> These files may be available here:
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Ssms.exe_43575f69ad1e116788ab6f8aefadf1dd8e3c827e_ec2160f4_4616dc68-1cbc-47cd-aa89-c03e560e8927
>
> Analysis symbol:
> Rechecking for solution: 0
> Report Id: e2d6335c-1bf1-4113-bbb2-fcc29a8aafee
> Report Status: 268435456
> Hashed bucket: 6dbc69c42400d68b52a748c5c2b65f42
> Cab Guid: 0
>
> **We get an Application Error in the Event Viewer as follows**
>
> Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2019.150.18424.0, time stamp: 0x62b10e6f
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.2251, time stamp: 0x0d929ca0
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
> Fault offset: 0x0012e062
> Faulting process id: 0xe918
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d90fdbb55ea3f9
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
> Report Id: e2d6335c-1bf1-4113-bbb2-fcc29a8aafee
> Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> **.NET Runtime Error from Event Viewer**
>
> ```
> Application: Ssms.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException
> at MS.Internal.PointUtil.FromPoint(System.Windows.Point)
> at MS.Internal.PointUtil.ScreenToClient(System.Windows.Point, System.Windows.PresentationSource)
> at System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice.GetPosition(System.Windows.IInputElement)
> at System.Windows.Controls.PopupControlService.OnPostProcessInput(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs)
> at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventHandler, System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs)
> at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
> at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
> at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
> at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
> at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
> at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
> at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
> at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
> at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>
>
> **The referenced .WER file's contents:**
>
> Version=1
> EventType=CLR20r3
> EventTime=133155113372246876
> ReportType=2
> Consent=1
> UploadTime=133155113388966378
> ReportStatus=268435456
> ReportIdentifier=4616dc68-1cbc-47cd-aa89-c03e560e8927
> IntegratorReportIdentifier=e2d6335c-1bf1-4113-bbb2-fcc29a8aafee
> Wow64Host=34404
> Wow64Guest=332
> NsAppName=Ssms.exe
> OriginalFilename=SSMS.EXE
> AppSessionGuid=0000e918-0001-002a-f9a3-5eb5db0fd901
> TargetAppId=W:0006eb54dba05bdf3918169dc524753b6d1a00000904!0000b8c28928d48e0ba90f7f75a3bcfe48b86650103f!Ssms.exe
> TargetAppVer=2022//06//21:00:18:55!b3643!Ssms.exe
> BootId=4294967295
> ServiceSplit=49545216
> TargetAsId=14655
> IsFatal=1
> EtwNonCollectReason=4
> Response.BucketId=6dbc69c42400d68b52a748c5c2b65f42
> Response.BucketTable=5
> Response.LegacyBucketId=1344123028005871426
> Response.type=4
> Sig[0].Name=Problem Signature 01
> Sig[0].Value=Ssms.exe
> Sig[1].Name=Problem Signature 02
> Sig[1].Value=2019.150.18424.0
> Sig[2].Name=Problem Signature 03
> Sig[2].Value=62b10e6f
> Sig[3].Name=Problem Signature 04
> Sig[3].Value=PresentationCore
> Sig[4].Name=Problem Signature 05
> Sig[4].Value=4.8.4579.0
> Sig[5].Name=Problem Signature 06
> Sig[5].Value=631946f9
> Sig[6].Name=Problem Signature 07
> Sig[6].Value=4834
> Sig[7].Name=Problem Signature 08
> Sig[7].Value=0
> Sig[8].Name=Problem Signature 09
> Sig[8].Value=System.OutOfMemoryException
> DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
> DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.19044.2.0.0.256.48
> DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
> DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
> DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
> DynamicSig[22].Value=2beb
> DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
> DynamicSig[23].Value=2beba6fb4680d73a8c78ca7c24ccdb46
> DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
> DynamicSig[24].Value=fdae
> DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
> DynamicSig[25].Value=fdae5d07ca7a3e113815289fb726fabc
> UI[2]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe
> LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe
> LoadedModule[1]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
> LoadedModule[2]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
> LoadedModule[3]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
> LoadedModule[4]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
> LoadedModule[5]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
> LoadedModule[6]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP120.dll
> LoadedModule[7]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120.dll
> LoadedModule[8]=C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.1110_none_a8625c1886757984\COMCTL32.dll
> LoadedModule[9]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
> LoadedModule[10]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
> LoadedModule[11]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
> LoadedModule[12]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
> LoadedModule[13]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
> LoadedModule[14]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
> LoadedModule[15]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
> LoadedModule[16]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
> LoadedModule[17]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
> LoadedModule[18]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ShellExtensions\Platform\appenvstub.dll
> LoadedModule[19]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
> LoadedModule[20]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
> LoadedModule[21]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\VCRUNTIME140.dll
> LoadedModule[22]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
> LoadedModule[23]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
> LoadedModule[24]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
> LoadedModule[25]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
> LoadedModule[26]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\MSVCP140.dll
> LoadedModule[27]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
> LoadedModule[28]=C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.19041.2251_none_d9513b1fe1046fc7\gdiplus.dll
> LoadedModule[29]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mscoree.dll
> LoadedModule[30]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ScriptControl32_16207.dll
> LoadedModule[31]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcrypt.dll
> LoadedModule[32]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
> LoadedModule[33]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHCORE.DLL
> LoadedModule[34]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll
> LoadedModule[35]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Wldp.dll
> LoadedModule[36]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
> LoadedModule[37]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
> LoadedModule[38]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
> LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
> LoadedModule[40]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\msenv.dll
> LoadedModule[41]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UIAutomationCore.DLL
> LoadedModule[42]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DWrite.dll
> LoadedModule[43]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d9.dll
> LoadedModule[44]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USP10.dll
> ```

We're not really "doing" anything - SSMS is simply sitting idle.

Comment: Seems like out-of-memory exception. SSMS requires 2GB of free RAM minimum - how much RAM do you have in your PC? Maybe you have running other software, which consumes available memory?
Here are requirements for SSMS: https://red9.com/blog/microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/

Comment: Great question, @VillageTech and I meant to include that in my OP.  My machine has 15.3GB of RAM, only 11.1 of which is currently in use.